# Защищенная система лайков

Tags: jquery, ajax, php, javascript, mysql

Доброе время суток, господа
Вопрос следующий: как сделать защищенную систему лайков? (ведь через ajax может пойти их накрутка)
Порывшись немного в кодах хэшкода, я нашел, что лайки ставятся тегам ссылок с атрибутом nofollow:

```
<a href="rate/200/up" rel="nofollow">Голосовать!</a>
```

А вот что дальше делать у меня ступор, господа. Как осуществить задуманное?
Вопрос стоит именно в безопасности. А как хранить-оно в принципе понятно. Что-то вроде таблицы likes в mysql с полями user и topic, чтобы был система 1пользователь-1лайк.
Или же есть более совершенный метод?

P.S. похоже, что спасает в самом начале скрипта такая фраза:

```
<?if (!isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'])) die('Хрен!');?>
```

Прав ли я?

Answer (score 2):

1. [nofollow](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nofollow) — это заголовок для роботов, чтобы они не ходили/не индексировали эти ссылки.
2. На сервере 100% проверяется авторизация юзера
3. Все запросы подписываются [токеном](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B6%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%85_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2), чтобы нельзя было накрутить при помощи скрытой  картики. [Статья](http://habrahabr.ru/post/144406/) на хабре.

P.S. В случае hashcode, все запросы имею дополнительный заголовок **X-CSRFToken**.

Comment: можете, пожалуйста, поподробней объяснить? а если хакер поставит этот заголовок? я как-то совсем не понял. обойтись <?if (!isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'])) die('Хрен!');?> нельзя?

Comment: Почитайте статью, там всё понятно объяснено. CSRF token — это не просто заголовок, через него непосредственно передается уникальный токен, выделенный на сервере, а сревер получая этот токен, сверяет его и только в этому случае выполняет нужное действие.

Answer (score 0):

А в чем проблема. В таблице делаете ключевыми столбцы user-topic (что бы были Unique) и не беспокоитесь, один пользователь не поставит лайк более одного раза. Все остальное уже заморочки безопасности более высокого уровня, всей системы (что бы нельзя было зарегистрировать over 9000 пользователей-ботов, кстати, как вариант, привязка к телефону)